# Problema ao abrir form dentro de panel

Tags: delphi

Estou tentando abrir um form dentro de um panel no Delphi, mas aparentemente, o form abre com o mesmo tamanho do panel, mas fora dele.

Fiz assim...

```
UniForm1.Parent := UniPanel1;
UniForm1.Show;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Experimente setar a propriedade do form `Position`para `poOwnerFormCenter`

Comment: Não fez diferença...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi com o seguinte código, além de trocar o *WindowState* de *wsMaximized* para *wsNormal* e o *Position* para *poDefaultPosOnly*.

```
UniForm1.Width := UniPanel1.Width;
UniForm1.Height := UniPanel1.Height;
```

Answer (score 0):

Se usares uma Frame em vez de um Form podes fazer o que pretendes.

```
  tuaFrame:=TUniFrame1.Create(self);
  tuaFrame.Parent:=teuPainel;
  tuaFrame.Align:=alclient;
  tuaFrame.Visible:=true;
```